# $\lim \int \sqrt[n]{f^{n} + g^{n}} d\mu$ exists as extended real number.

Tags: integration, measure-theory

Let $f, g$ be measurable on $(X, \mathcal{M}, \mu)$ with $0 \leq f \leq g$ a.e. Prove that $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \int \sqrt[n]{f^{n} + g^{n}} d\mu$$ exists as an extended real number. What is its value?

**So Far:** We know $\sqrt[n]{f^{n} + g^{n}} \leq \sqrt[n]{2g^{n}} \leq 2g$. Also, 
\begin{align}
\log(g) &\leq \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{\log(f^{n} + g^{n})}{n} \\
 &= \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{f^{n}\log(f) + g^{n}\log(g)}{f^{n} + g^{n}} & (\text{L'Hospital}) \\
 &\leq \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{f^{n}\log(g) + g^{n}\log(g)}{f^{n} + g^{n}} \\
 &= \log(g),
\end{align}

whence $\sqrt[n]{f^{n} + g^{n}} \rightarrow g$. Thus if $\int g d\mu < \infty$ then Dominated Convergence gives us
$$\int \sqrt[n]{f^{n} + g^{n}} d\mu \longrightarrow \int g d\mu.$$

**Where I'm Stuck:** If $\int g$ is not finite, I'm not quite sure how to show the limit exists in $[-\infty, \infty]$. According to Dominated Convergence Theorem on Wiki, it is necessary for $g$ to be integrable. So I cannot get an extended real number limit just from that theorem.

I also tried integrating over the sets $\{f < 1\}$ and $\{f \geq 1\}$. On the second set, $\frac{d}{dn}\sqrt[n]{f^{n} + g^{n}}$ is positive and I can apply Monotone Convergence Theorem over this set, which forgets about whether $\int g$ is infinite or not (if I remember correctly). But then integrating over the other set gets me at most $\int_{f< 1} \sqrt[n]{f^{n} + g^{n}} \leq \int_{f>1} \sqrt[n]{1 + g^{n}}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $g^n\le f^n+g^n\le 2g^n.$

Comment: Ah, so if $\int g = \infty$ then $\infty = \int g \leq \int \sqrt[n]{f^{n} + g^{n}} \implies \int \sqrt[n]{f^{n} + g^{n}} = \infty$, yes?

Comment: @Fred that's right.